# how can i play video from ftp server on local web page?

Tags: android, html, ftp, video-streaming

I want to build a local network web page like on WiFi network suppose I have an android device and I active a ftp server from android and started sharing the data from that server but the problem is that I can only navigate through device storage and download but I want to create a web page which utilize the server and instead of downloading the video it plays instead.

I tried using html video tag and pasted the video link. like

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VIDEO</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="1280" height="720" controls><source src="ftp://192.168.0.103:40129/Movie/The%205th%20Wave%20(2016)%20%5BYTS.AG%5D/The.5th.Wave.2016.720p.BluRay.x264-%5BYTS.AG%5D.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

All major web browsers are gradually [removing a support for FTP](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/chrome-and-firefox-developers-aim-to-remove-support-for-ftp/). So even if this works somehow, it won't sooner or later.

---

Instead, you will have to stream the video from (or via) your web server.

Comment: ok but i still wanna know because its not for development purpose for personal use..